Python nested dictionary to Tree
I am trying to display my nested dictionary as a Tree.
data = {"L1" : 
            {"sub L1" : 
                "sub sub L1"}, 
        "L2" :
            "sub L2", 
        "L3" :
            {"sub L3" :
                {"sub sub L3" :
                    "sub sub sub L3"}}}

As you can see, it's all text data and there is no real correlation between any of it.
I have tried networkx and dendograms but they seem to be breaking as I have a nested dictionary.
Is there a better way to do this?

"they seem to breaking " - show us your code and your expected output.

You can recursively traverse your dict and make a DiGraph from the collected edges :
import networkx as nx

def traverse(data, p="L0"):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for k, v in data.items():
            yield p, k
            yield from traverse(v, k)
    elif p is not None:
        yield p, data

DG = nx.DiGraph(traverse(data)) # or `Graph` to remove the arrows

# requires `pygraphviz`
from IPython.display import Image
Image(nx.nx_agraph.to_agraph(DG).draw(format="png", prog="dot"))



You need to unpack your data into a series of node chains.  Then you can add them to the graph in sequence.
data = {'L1': {'sub L1': 'sub sub L1'},
 'L2': 'sub L2',
 'L3': {'sub L3': {'sub sub L3': 'sub sub sub L3'}}}

def unpack(d, is_root=True):
    if is_root:
        root = []
    r = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        if is_root:
            r = []
            root.append(r)
        r.append(k)
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            r.extend(unpack(v, False))
        else:
            r.append(v)
    return root if is_root else r

node_lists = unpack(data)
node_lists
# returns:
[['L1', 'sub L1', 'sub sub L1'],
 ['L2', 'sub L2'],
 ['L3', 'sub L3', 'sub sub L3', 'sub sub sub L3']]

For plotting:
g = networkx.DiGraph()
for node_chain in node_lists:
    for a, b in zip(['root'] + node_chain, node_chain):
        g.add_edge(a, b)

pos = networkx.nx_pydot.graphviz_layout(g)
networkx.draw_networkx(g, pos)
networkx.draw_networkx_labels(g, pos)

